# Whitespace at top and within body div tags

Tags: html, css, whitespace

Can someone please just tell me what my sorry, stupid eyes are missing?

Whitespace appears at the top of my browser window, and between two div tag containers (all browsers.)

p, body, html, every div, all margin:0px;

Gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove the `margin-top: 20px;` off of `<div class="menucontainer">` and put `padding-top: 20px;` onto `<div class="lightsandcolorscontainer">`

The reasoning is that since it's the top most container it's margin-top put onto the parent container, I'm sure there's a W3C doc on why this is, but it's just like that. If you want to move something away that's the top element of a container, you need to use padding instead on it's parent.

Comment: Hey Patrick.  Thanks so much for enlightening me on this.  I've never come across this problem with a parent/container margin.  I guess I've never done that before, but I find it interesting that even though the parent container takes the first div tag's margin properties, using a developer tool (chrome inspect element, firebug, etc) it still returns 0px margin for that container.  Thank you for giving me a little insight as to why this was happening.

Comment: In these particular cases, it just comes down to tribal knowledge about the CSS Box Model. Developer tools only tell you the settings applied upon a container, not so much about the inheritance of cases like this one. Another to look out for is collapsing margins. For example, a bunch of `<p/>` tags in a row with `margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px` will only have `10px` of space between them, not `20px` as expected.

Answer (score 2):

The margin top of your `menu-container` div has `margin-top: 20px;` I saw that using FireBug.

Answer (score 0):

`.menucontainer` has `margin-top: 20px;`

set to `margin-top: 0;`

`.centercontainer` has `margin: 10px auto;`

set to `margin: 0 auto;`

and add `overflow: hidden;` (to `.centercontainer`)

Developer tools in Chrome is a huge help, as is Firebug in Firefox :)

EDIT: if you want your `.menucontainer` to be 20px lower, add `padding-top: 20px;` to `.lightsandcolourcontainer`

Also, your content width is set to 1000px - beware of this width as you're allowing only 24px for a horizontal scroll bar, which may have the side effect of an ugly and unnecessary vertical scroll bar appearing in some browsers. Sticking to 960px - 980px max page width is a web standard adopted to prevent the vertical scroll from appearing on the majority of visitors' browsers (since 1024 x 768 is/was the most prevalent resolution of visitors' monitors).